# How to disable auto-injector (magic discovery of injector types) in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs has this nice feature of auto discovery of the providers based on a function arguments.
For example, if I want to use $http in some function i would call it like that:

```
$inject.invoke(function ($http) {

});
```

Angularjs will "know" what are my dependencies. It will figure it out by reading my function's body and based on argument names it will know.

However there is a problem when you would like to minify your code. Minifier will change arguments names. That's why we should use this notation:

```
$inject.invoke(['$http', function ($http) {}]);
```

or this notation:

```
function Foo ($http) {}
Foo.$inject = ['$http'];

$inject.invoke(Foo);
```

We should always in the end minify our code. So we should avoid using this magic (first example) notation.

And now my problem:

I'm trying to minify my js code and angularjs cannot resolve a provider name.
I can't find a place where i haven't specified `.$inject = [...]`. Now it just says: `"Unknown provider a"` and i don't know what function is it referring to.

Is it possible to turn off angularjs auto discover (auto-injector) of providers? I would test and repair my code before minifying.

So, I'm wondering how to disable this "magic" angularjs deduction. 
Since I always minify my code I want angularjs to yell at me when I will accidentally use this superheroic evil.

How to turn it off?

Comment: What is wrong with this question? Why minus?

Comment: People is weird. I fixed it for you.

Comment: This question should really be titled "How do I minify my Angular code without breaking auto-injection?" or something like that. There will be other people looking for this I'm sure.

Comment: I just want to know how to disable this auto-injection. I know that during minifying I should use .$inject = [] or ["Abc", function(Abc) {}] notation. But how to make angularjs yell at me during development?

Comment: You can also use "break on any exception" and debug and go to caller to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 1.3.0-beta.6 onwards angularjs supports ng-strict-di option which can be used along with ng-app directive to disable auto-injection.

From [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

> if this attribute is present on the app element, the injector will be
>   created in "strict-di" mode. This means that the application will fail
>   to invoke functions which do not use explicit function annotation (and
>   are thus unsuitable for minification), as described in the Dependency
>   Injection guide, and useful debugging info will assist in tracking
>   down the root of these bugs

Answer (score 8):

Just edit the source.  Find 'function annotate', and replace the fn == 'function' block with something like this:

```
if (typeof fn == 'function') {
  console.log("Bad magic injection in "+fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, ''));
}
```

Comment: After doing this angularjs always throws an error: "Bad magic injection in function $LocaleProvider". So angular itself stopped working. I've found the place where i ommit to inject manually dependencies and now can minify successfully. $LocaleProvider was not causing my problem.

Comment: Andy's tip is great,  but you just have to change to "console.log()" and not throw error.   because you put this code in a local uncompressed angular.js,   so with andy's "throw error",  it'll halt immediately on angular's first internal provider ($LocaleProvider),  and will not even reach you own code.       Just do console.log at the position andy gave you and you'll find the problem immediately.

Comment: This tip is great and worked to debug in our case. We found the culprit function was logged immediately before the "unknown provider" error.

To clarify add this to the angular.js source file. Also we used the js beautifier to re-format our minified code which made recognizing the function even easier.

Answer (score 4):

update:

If anyone needs this because of trying to minify, maybe here is another possible solution

[ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin). It is an AngularJS application minifier project.

Not sure if this help.

According to Igor Minar,

You should make something like this

```
factory('Phone', function($resource){ ... }))
```

to

```
factory('Phone', ['$resource', function($resource){ ... })])
```

Here is the official doc from [Dev guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

> $inject Annotation
>
> To allow the minifers to rename the function parameters and still be
>   able to inject right services the function needs to be annotate with
>   the $inject property. The $inject property is an array of service
>   names to inject.
>
> ```
> var MyController = function(renamed$scope, renamedGreeter) {
> ...
> }
> MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
> ```
>
> Care must be taken that the $inject annotation is kept in sync with
>   the actual arguments in the function declaration.
>
> This method of annotation is useful for controller declarations since
>   it assigns the annotation information with the function

Comment: Thanks, for that. However the problem is that I've got it everywhere in my code. Well not everywhere, somewhere I missed it and now don't know where i missed it. I now want to disable this "angular auto magic" option at all so that during development interpreter will yell at me when i will not insert .$inject or ['Abc', function(Abc) {}]. I would be able to fix a problem when I'm working on this peace of code.

Comment: OK, now I understand your question. Maybe you should put this in your question as well.